# ニューラルネットで似たような値ばかり推定する原因

Tags: 機械学習, keras

最近機械学習を始めたものです．
以下のような条件でKerasを使用してニューラルネットを構築したのですが
思うような結果が得られません．
入力：7次元/出力：2次元
入力は0,1,2,3のスコアで出力は50~110の間で５刻みの値
全データ数は1000件ほどで入力から出力を推定する回帰学習

画像がその出力結果です
推定精度が高ければ高いほど対角線上にプロットされるという評価指標です
しかしなぜかこのような帯状のプロットになってしまっています
(何を入力しても似たような値を推定している状況)
[image: 推定値と真値が一致していれば対角線の近くにプロットされる]

Comment: 学習に使ったデータの数が少ない、あるいはデータが不適切である可能性はありませんか？

Comment: どのような構成のニューラルネットワークを作ったのですか？　出力(判定結果)の種類が13種類（50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100,105,110)と多いのですが、それに対して学習に使うデータ数が1000件ほどというのは十分なのでしょうか。

Comment: 使用したニューラルネットワークの構造は入力層7つ・中間層8つ・出力層1つです

Comment: データ量が不十分であることは重々承知しているのですが、データ量が少ないと必ずしもこのような一定の値ばかり吐くようなモデルになってしまうものなのでしょうか？

Comment: 出力層が１つということは、グラフは出力層の値（X軸:observed）が0.1～0.9辺りに散らばるという事を示しているのですか？　では、Y軸(predicted)は何を示しているのでしょう？

Comment: X軸には0〜1にスケーリングされた出力値がプロットされてます。一方でY軸にはモデルを用いた推定値を出力させています。推定精度が高いほど対角線上にプロットが集まり、モデルの性能が高いことがわかると言った感じです。